# How to import a 'Feature'?

Tags: 7, nodes, features, importing-exporting

I have exported certain items with features module and have my *.tar file, where do I go in drupal to import this Feature in my destination site???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found my answer. 
Features creates a module that I need to import in the destination site.